Are 1 Samual 13:3 and 14:1 two separate events or the same event?

Are 1 Samual 13:3 and 14:1 two separate events or the same event?

3 Jonathan attacked the Philistine outpost at Geba, and the Philistines heard about it. Then Saul had the trumpet blown throughout the land and said, "Let the Hebrews hear!" [1Sa 13:3 NIV]


1 One day Jonathan son of Saul said to his young armor-bearer, "Come, let's go over to the Philistine outpost on the other side." But he did not tell his father. [1Sa 14:1 NIV]

Then verse 4 of 1 Samual 13 says Saul carried out the attack.
“Saul has attacked the Philistine outpost"
In Rachel Angel's dissertation, How the Mighty Have Fallen: The Saul and Jonathan Traditions in the Book of Samuel and Early Israel she writes:
"When these two chapters are placed side by side, they form what some scholars see as either a doublet or two competing narratives.262 Jonathan unexpectedly attacks the Philistine נציב in 13:3 and again, unexpectedly attacks the Philistine מצב in 14:13. Several scholars have explained the presence of these two similar action scenes by suggesting that there are two different traditions within chapters 13-14. Adolphe Lods outlines two strands that have been intertwined in the current text. In one, Saul is the true instigator, a theory rooted in the announcement in 13:4 that Saul has killed the נציב. In the other strand, Jonathan plays that role.263 Similarly, Stoebe embraces the theory that chapters 13-14 were composed of at least two entirely independent tales about Philistine wars woven together, one featuring Saul’s heroic deed at Gibeah and the other focusing on Jonathan’s later feat at Geba.264 J. Maxwell Miller, in basic agreement with Stoebe’s theory, suggests that the two separate tales reflect parallel versions of a single tradition that existed separately and contemporaneously and were combined, or dovetailed, in chapters 13-14.265



https://www.academia.edu/109020244/How_the_Mighty_Have_Fallen_The_Saul_and_Jonathan_Traditions_in_the_Book_of_Samuel_and_Early_Israelpg 101-102



This is one of those academic theories that almost sound plausible until one reads the details of the story.  The differences between the two are significant:




1 Samuel 13
1 Samuel 14




Summary
The incident initiates the war
The incident initiates a battle


Timing
The events take seven days to begin the war and offer sacrifices
The events initiated immediately and are over in one day


Troop location
Saul had 2000 men at Michmash; Jonathon had 1000 men at Geba
Saul had 600 men at Migron - Jonathon was there as well because they discovered his absence


What happened
No battle recorded - Saul rebuked but the Philistines appear to have taken Saul's position at Micmash (V16)
Israel wins the battle, saved by the LORD.  The battle extends to Beth-aven. Saul attempts to kill Jonathon, but the men save Jonathon


Troop condition
Saul's troops very frightened
Troops united and stand up to Saul


Ceremonial component
Samuel involved and waited on. Saul offers an unlawful sacrifice
Ahijah the priest wearing an ephod asks what to do next. Lots cast to find the guilty person.



Thus, it appears these are two separate incidents - one that initiated the war with the philistines and the next is a battle with the philistines - both initiated by Jonathon.

There is no doubt (as @Dottard has shown) that there are significant differences between the two stories. However, this does not disprove the fact that we may be dealing with a "doublet or competing narratives." If critical scholars are correct, ancient stories circulated through oral traditions for centuries before reaching their current written form.  Having evolved into different written accounts, they were then compiled into the text we see today. Here were are dealing with events that reached their near-final form about 300 years or more after the fact.
A simpler example is found for example in the two stories of Sarah's entering a foreign king's harem. They differ in important respects (in one it is Pharaoh's harem, in the other Abimelech's) but source critics believe the two stories have the same origin in an ancient folk tale. Regarding the OP's example, John William Weavers writing in the Interpreter's Bible One-Volume Commentary, held that an editor inserted an alternate narrative' in ch. 13 to strength the idea that Saul's kingdom had been rejected by God.

The D editor may have placed the story in this context to prove that
Saul was rejected before undertaking his first act of kingship. Could
the 2 years of verse 1 then be intended as the length of time that he
ruled before his rejection?

Be that as it may, the basic idea is that there was more than one written version at the editor's disposal when he worked on 2 Samuel, and these were combined by him as if they were two separate events. Whether the editor himself knew that the two accounts described the same event is anyone's guess.
Conclusion: the issue amounts to a matter of opinion. Those who believe in the direct inspiration of the Bible reject the idea that these accounts originally described the same event. Critical scholars have various theories about it.
